# Draw a Line in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a line in Python, but when I run the code below, this line never appears. In fact, I need to make a field with 4x4 sections, but let's begin with a line.
My code:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import*

width = 1000
height = 500
screen_color = (49, 150, 100)
line_color = (255, 0, 0)

def main():
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    screen.fill(screen_color)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.draw.line(screen,line_color, (60, 80), (130, 100))

    while True:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == QUIT:
                sys.exit(0)
main()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I believe you should have your line flipped in the game loop!

Comment: You are only drawing the line once, therefor it disappears immediatly. Just put the line of code for the line you draw in the while loop and it should draw the line. Also put your "pygame.display.flip()" at the end of your loop.

Comment: @AJ I'm late to the party, but the line isn't disappearing at all, rather the screen just hasn't been updated. `pygame.display.update()` is also a good alternative, though flip and update have some minor differences I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 21):

You have to update the display of your computer with `pygame.display.flip` after you draw the line.

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, Color_line, (60, 80), (130, 100))
pygame.display.flip()
```

That's usually done at the bottom of the while loop once per frame.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a width to the line (the last parameter to the line method) and update the display

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, Color_line, (60, 80), (130, 100), 1)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do pygame.display.flip() after  you draw your line you are doing this:

```
screen.fill(color)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.draw.line(...)
```

The problem is you're covering the line up before it can show up.
Do this instead:

```
screen.fill(color)
pygame.draw.line(...)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add
`pygame.display.flip()` after you draw your line.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pygame as pg

# Initializing the screen
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((200, 200))

# Setting a white background
screen.fill(pg.Color("white"))

# Initializing event loop (1 pass = 1 frame)
while True:
    # Drawing a red line from (0, 100) to (200, 100) of thickness 5
    pg.draw.line(screen, pg.Color("red"), (0, 100), (200, 100), 5)
    
    # Refreshing screen, otherwise no changes will occur
    pg.display.update()
    
    # Restarting event loop in 5 seconds
    # (can also use a pg.time.Clock to specify the framerate)
    pg.time.wait(5000)
```

The event loop isn't necessary in this snippet, but it's good practice.
As well, the screen should typically only be refreshed at the end of the event loop, as updating changes individually can get rather inefficient, instead of updating them in compound.
For specifying the framerate rather than waiting hardcoded times after each frame, see [pygame.time.Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and its [tick](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) method.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to do:
pygame.display.flip()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30974052)